# Visual Studio does not see Microsoft Office references

Tags: visual-studio-2013, reference, ms-office

My point was to use Microsoft Office libraries, e. g. Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint. Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2013 cannot see them between references when I am trying to add them to the project using Search option of Reference Manager. However, they are in the folder among "Program Files (x86)" (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Visual Studio Tools for Office\PIA). I can only add them manually, like browsing and giving their location, not through the search option in "COM" in Reference Manager.

**How can it be explained?**

Microsoft Office itself is not running in computer, but I installed these assemblies manually.

Comment: Q: Did you do the install, checking "Net programmability Support"?  Q: If not, is there anything preventing you from doing so?  The issue is that you need the files, and you *also* need the COM registration.  "Install" is the cleanest way to accomplish both.  See my links below for more details.

Comment: Thanks. But as I said in the question I have no MS Office in the computer, and not planning to have it (since it cost). The plan is to have these assemblies without the office.

Comment: OK.  You can try installing [Office Tools](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/office-tools-vs.aspx) per my link below.  But you're probably screwed if you want to do MS-Office development on a machine without MS-Office :(

Answer (score 1):

Suggestions:

1. Re-run your MS-Office install.  Do an "Update".  Be sure to check ".Net Programmability Support".
2. If you still don't see the Interop libraries in Project > References > COM, then try installing Office Development Tools:

   https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/office-tools-vs.aspx
3. Links:

   - [How to Install Office Primary Interop Assemblies (PIA)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kh3965hw.aspx)
   - [Cannot find Microsoft.Office.Interop Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21986323/cannot-find-microsoft-office-interop-visual-studio)

It sounds like you've got (at least some) of the right files ... but the components and/or typelibs were never correctly registered with COM.

You must do an "install" for things to work properly.

Answer (score 1):

A COM server application should be installed on the PC. Only in that case COM references will contain corresponding entries. PIAs and COM servers are different things. PIAs are used for marshalling your property or method calls to COM servers (unmanaged world).

Comment: That's exactly what I tried to say below.  Unless the COM/ActiveX components are "registered", you won't see them in MSVS.  Installing MS-Office (along with checking ".Net Programmability Support") should do everything that's needed.  Simply copying PIA files won't.

Comment: ".Net Programmability support" doesn't play any role in that case.