# Interop with Excel 2016 in Visual Basic Express 2010

Tags: excel, vb.net, vba, visual-studio-2010

I am working on a project I have in mind. I want some of my calculations to be done in Excel as it is much easier there. The Excel will just be my computing back-end while the user will mainly interact with the Visual Basic front-end for user-friendliness.

From what I remember on my undergraduate programming class (Introductory VB for Solving Engineering Problems), I'll have to add a reference to my project in order to import Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel in order to create instances of Excel. My problem is that I can't seem to find the library that I need (Microsoft Office). I have Office 2016 and from what I have read, Microsoft does not anymore (or have not yet) provide Primary Interop Assemblies for 2016. How do I go around this?

EDIT: 
[image: LIST OF COM References]

Comment: Why are you using VS2010?

Comment: This was the program provided to us during my college days. And it's not even Visual Studio. It's simply Visual Basic Express 2010.

Comment: I have Office 2016 on my computer but I still use the 15.0 object library and interop...always works fine for me. Office is backwards compatible with the older frameworks, just have to be careful when coding using the 15.0 framework and running it on an older Office version

Comment: Are you on Visual Basic Express 2010? How did you add the reference to the object library? In the COM tab, I only have Microsoft Office 16.0 Object Library.

Comment: Yeah, I just grab the highest available version of the object library from the com tab, and then add interop from the assemblies tab (i think that'd be the .net tab in your case)

Comment: Your COM tab shows no evidence at all that you have Office installed.  Hard to guess what you *do* have installed, maybe the Office 365 product.  Or the 64-bit version, VS can only show entries for 32-bit products.  If you see Excel.exe somewhere in the "Microsoft Office" directory then run Tlbimp.exe to generate the interop library.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot find Microsoft.Office.Interop Visual Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21986323/cannot-find-microsoft-office-interop-visual-studio)