# Adding Outlook Interop To Visual Studio Project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, outlook

I am using Visual Studio Community 2015, and currently trying to add Outlook Interop to a project.

Currently I have added the two COM references:

- Microsoft Office 15.0 Object Library.
- Microsoft Office 16.0 Object Library.

Unfortunately I cannot find a reference to the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook in Assemblies, and when using:

```
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
```

I get the error message:

```
The type or namespace name 'Interop' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Office' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

From what I have read online, I should be able to see all the Interop assemblies as references available to add, is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should be able to.

Right click "References" in the Solution Explorer > "Add Reference" > Select COM on the left hand side > (Sort by Name)* > Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook > OK

*For me the list is never in order, so I always have to sort the list, might be the case with you too

This worked for me, there are also other suggestions here: [Cannot find Microsoft.Office.Interop Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21986323/cannot-find-microsoft-office-interop-visual-studio)