# Visual Studio 2017 no reference to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Tags: excel, visual-studio, reference

Upgrade to VS 2017 and now I there is no references available to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Where did the reference go?

Comment: Did you try add reference > select "Assemblies" > "Browse"  > C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 17.0\Visual Studio Tools for Office\PIA\Officexx ?

Comment: The installation did not create a a folder \Microsoft Visual Studio 17.0\. I reinstalled the program twice. I also Installed the Office developer tools for Visual Basic. Under Individual componets in the Visual Studio 2017 Installer.

Comment: see answer below.  (It's a good idea to check Google before asking.)  Remember the folder path may vary on your machine.  You might need to poke around a bit, both on your machine, and on Google.

Comment: where are the VS program files housed then? Should be listed on your environment path I am guessing if not search ....

Comment: The visual studio is in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional. I searched for the Visual Studio Tools for Office and the folder does not exist.

Comment: Did you select Microsoft Office Developer Tools for installation initially?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21986323/cannot-find-microsoft-office-interop-visual-studio?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 0):

> You should be able to "**Add reference**", select "**Assemblies**", press the "**Browse**" button, traverse to a path along this line (most likely close to your machine but slightly different):
>
> `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Visual Studio Tools for Office\PIA\Office15`
>
> Then you should see to select:
>
> [image: img]

([**Source**](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1b88af70-3022-4e17-b620-0423528f9a45/how-can-i-add-reference-to-microsoftofficeinteropexcel-in-visual-studio-2017-community-edition?forum=exceldev) Stack Overflow user: [@karen-payne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5509738/karen-payne))

Comment: @karen-payne **"ping!"** (I wasn't sure if the in-answer tag would ping you.)

Comment: The issue was resolved by removing any reference This includes deleting from the registery. The uninstall did nor remove everything.to a previous version of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Visual Studio Installer under Individual Components and click 'Office Developer Tools for Visual Studio. This solved it for me after lots of headaches.

[image: Go to Visual Studio Installer under Individual Components and click 'Office Developer Tools for Visual Studio.]